# Build a JPA application with Netbean 6.8 and Glassfish v3

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa

I am trying to learn JPA, and Sun tutorial on JPA ("order" application) is hard to understand. The tutorial does not show me how the mapping between JPA and the actual Datasource, and does not explain various annotation they used in the tutorial. I did some google search and I did not find any thing good and basic. Does any of you know a basic JPA tutorial somewhere that I can learn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_2_1/guides/jpa/tutorial.html